# Error al crear html con js - funciona una parte en firefox pero en chrome no

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente problema, creo un html con datos de un json es una lista y en la lista hay unos botones, en firefox crea la lista con los botones bien pero en chrome crea la lista pero los botones no los muestra, en el inspector de chrome si muestra que creo los botones pero no se ven en el diseño.

Mi codigo es el siguiente.

```
function listarObjetosEvento(evento) { // aca jonny
    $.post("objectsofevents?", {accion: 'Objetosevento', evento: evento}, function (rs) {
        if (rs != '[]') {

            $('.listadeobjetos').empty();

            var json = JSON.parse(rs);
            for (let item of json) {
                document.getElementById('listaobjetos' + evento).innerHTML += "<option id=''  class='btn  list-group-itemobjetos list-group-item-action text-gray-600  mb-1'" +
                        "data-toggle='list'>" +
                        item.objetonombre + "<button type='button' class='btn btn-circle bg-info ml-1 text-gray-200 float-right' onclick='verCaracteristicas(" + item.idobjeto + ");'><i class='fas fa-search' title='Consultar'></i></button>" +
                        "<button type='button' class='btn bg-danger text-gray-200 btn-circle float-right ml-1' title='Eliminar de mi lista' onclick='confirmEliminarObj(" + item.idobjeto + ", `" + item.objetonombre + "`)'><i class='fas fa-trash'></i></button>" +
                        "<button type='button' class='btn btn-circle bg-success text-gray-200 float-right' title='Cambiar.' onclick='traspasoObjeto(" + item.idobjeto + ", `" + item.objetonombre + "`);' ><i class='fas fa-history fa-1x'></i></button>" +
                        "</option> ";
            }
            $('#collapse' + evento).collapse('toggle');


        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Saludos. Te sugiero usar para los `type=`, `id=` y demás la comilla doble **`"`**; esto con el objeto que en las llamadas a funciones que allí tienes lo que sea texto lo coloques entre comilla simple **`'`**; por ejemplo que `onclick='traspasoObjeto(" + item.idobjeto + ", `" + item.objetonombre + "`);'` sea `onclick=\"traspasoObjeto(" + item.idobjeto + ", '" + item.objetonombre + "');\"`

Comment: Hola @RobertoLeOr, gracias por tu comentario probe tu recomenacion pero sigue sin mostrarme los botones

Comment: Ya lo solucione, cambie el option por un div.